How to create a WebDeploy package for an SDK style Web Project in .NET8.0
For older style projects, I was essentially trying to use the Package target (which doesn't seem to exist in the SDK style web projects) like this:
<MSBuild Projects="%(WebsiteProjects.FullPath)" Targets="Package"
                 Properties="Configuration=$(ProjectConfiguration);PackageLocation=$(PackagesDir)\%(WebsiteProjects.Filename)_WebDeploy.zip;@(WebDeployProperties)"
                 Condition="'@(WebDeployProperties)'!='' And '@(WebsiteProjects)'!='' />

Now I just get an error message saying target "Package" doesn't exist.
In VS, I can still right-click the project and use Publish to create the package but how do I do this via MSBuild directly now?
